# How to differentiate different browser socket in node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I working on a chat application in Node.js., that can be intregrated to a web site

## Situation

user A is logined into  the chat integrated site,  using the browser 'Mozille'.

And the same user(ie A) is logined in another browser chrome.

Now, user A  has logout from the mozille browser .

How can i find out, user has logout from mozille browser

Iam using socket.io for chat application.

So is there any way to identify  the browser from the socket object

Following is my code

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            console.log("connected");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`socket.request.headers['user-agent']` contains the information about the browser.

PS: `socket.request` is the same as `req` in Express routes, so it works in both cases.

The library [`ua-parser`](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser) comes in handy to extract the information.

```
var UAparser = require('ua-parser').parse;
var useragent = UAparser(req.headers['user-agent']).ua.toString();
//=> Firefox 38.0
//=> Chrome 42.0.2311
```